# Virtual Keyboard disappears when touch on input:text iscroll4

Tags: html, cordova, iscroll4

keyboard pops up and goes down when clicked on input text.
i'using iscroll 4 cordova 1.6 technologies.
when user touches a text input the keyboard pops up and disappears from the screen
does any1 hav solution for it
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that ....app is able not focusing on the text area ....whenever user click on text area ...

The solution is  `document.getElementById('id').focus();`

id of text field.

Answer (score 0):

well for that you need to modify iScroll.js

1) take iScroll v4.1.9
2) change code for "onBeforeScrollStart" line #100 to this

var target = e.target;
                while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;
                if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA')
                e.preventDefault();

3) change code for "_start" line #317 add this code

```
_start: function (e) {

    if (e.target && e.target.type != undefined) {
        var tagname = event.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (tagname == "input" || tagname == "button" || tagname == "textarea") {// stuff we need to allow
            return;
        }
    }

    var that = this,
        point = hasTouch ? e.touches[0] : e,
        matrix, x, y,
        c1, c2;
```

Comment: did that worked for you!! i also have modified few part now its working well